# Sci-fi or Fantasy adult fiction novel read in the 80's about a man who taps into a primal force to lose weight

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a book that I read in the 80's, so 30-39 years ago. It was science fiction or possibly fantasy. A man was looking to lose weight. He taps into something primal through some experiments and meditation. He did lose weight, but also experienced other changes. He became stronger, faster, and more aggressive. Possible but uncertain details were there being a friend helping or running the experiment as well as a girlfriend. Also, there was a scene about him fighting a master with fighting sticks. This was English and as I was reading the Tor edition *Conan* novels it is likely this was adult fiction as well. Unfortunately this everything I can recall, and some of these details are a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Welcome back! And thank you for splitting your query. I made a few updates in your question based upon what I thought were the words you were going for.

Comment: Thank you. I rushed it and made some basic mistakes. I appreciate you cleaning it up.  There is another one that I looking for but I am doing some searching here and web searches before I post.

Comment: It doesn't fit all the cases but I think of *Erections, Ejaculations, Exhibitions
and General Tales of
Ordinary Madness* by Charles Bukowski, a book of short novels with one where the main characters is overweight. A witch tells him to tap his belly every day and he begins to lose weight, but gets also shorter, and the witch replaces his girlfriend. Maybe it's not that at all, but let's try:)

Comment: @Lyzvaleska Thank you but unfortunately, that is not the one.

Comment: If not for the bit about stick fighting, I might think this was one of the goldie oldies of science fiction: Robert A. Heinlein's "Waldo" (1942). Waldo was born with a genetic disorder that made his muscles very weak, but he first overcame this by living in his own private space station in zero-gee, while inventing "waldoes" which allowed him to do delicate work or heavy lifting down on Earth via remote control . . . and then later he learned to tap into cosmic forces that made him able to become a *very athletic* man (as well as achieving some other remarkable things).

Comment: @Lorendiac Sounds like a great story worth checking out. This is set in "modern" time, rather than in the past or the in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost certainly *The Kundalini Equation* by *Steven Barnes*, published in 1986. It has the hero, Adam Ludlum, trying to lose weight and become fit, finding a manuscript that details a system of meditation and visualization that allows him to tap into some primal energy. He becomes stronger, faster and instinctively duplicate different martial arts. There is the stick fighting martial artist and his growing aggression.

There is a nice essay from the author about writing it [here](https://stevenbarneslife.wordpress.com/2017/05/06/writing-the-kundalini-equation/).

[image: The Kundalini Equation front cover]